# C# drawing on custom controls

Tags: c#

so I've created a custom control and I wanted to draw on that control
now the problem is that I can't use OnPaint event because I want to
draw at different times with different conditions.

here is the custom control function to draw a rectangle

```js
public void DrawARectangle(int x,int y,int height,int width)
{
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, height, width);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, height, width);
}
```

and I basically call it from my form , but it doesn't draw anything even after using the update() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();` This is almost always **wrong**.

Use the `Paint/OnPaint` event and its `e.Graphics` parameter! Store the coordinates somewhere and be prepared to **always** draw everthing..

*I can't use OnPaint event because I want to draw at different times with different conditions.* Yes. But you **must**!

This is how graphics work in winforms. This only **sounds** wasteful but..: The system also needs to call this event when the window must be restored, so there is no way around it if you want your drawing to **persist**..

Only **non-persistent** graphics operations like displaying a dynamic rubber-band rectangle or a line that follows the mouse, are ok with a `Graphics` object you get from `control.CreateGraphics()`. And measurements without drawing...

Trigger re-drawing by calling `Invalidate` on your control whenever your data have changed.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `Control.OnPaint` to do your custom drawing. Otherwise all of your drawings will be erased after the next repaint of your control.
The idea is you may store your rectangles in a list. Then in your `Control.OnPaint`, you do the drawing based on that list.

Comment: well I am attempting to make a map like control where it will keep updating constantly , but I guess if I can't make it as a custom control then make it on the form it self.

Comment: @Diab, even you put directly in the form. You also need to do in Form.OnPaint event. The principal is still the same.

Comment: I did draw doing that a multiple times on form and it worked , maybe you miss understood me , I want to draw after the OnPaint event occurs I don't see why it has to occur again or repaint by it self.